# Why isn't Lord Venkateswara included in avatars of Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, venkateshwara

Why isn't Lord Venkateswara included in avatars of Lord Vishnu even though Lord Venkateswara is a form of Lord Vishnu?